# Abstract class reference implementation classes

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, abstract

I've got the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Period
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    protected abstract DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    protected abstract DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

With the following implementation:

```
public class MonthlyPeriod : Period
{
    private DateTimeOffset startDate { get; set; }

    public MonthlyPeriod(DateTimeOffset startDate)
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    protected override DateTimeOffset EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return startDate.AddMonths(1).AddTicks(-1);
        }

        set
        {
            startDate = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1);
        }
    }

    protected override DateTimeOffset StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return startDate;
        }

        set
        {
            startDate = new DateTimeOffset(value.Year, value.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, value.Offset);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is include the following abstract methods on the abstract class:

```
public abstract Period GetPreviousPeriod();
public abstract Period GetNextPeriod();
```

And then in the implementation have them return `MonthlyPeriod` specifically:

```
public override MonthlyPeriod GetNextPeriod() => new MonthlyPeriod(EndDate.AddDays(1));
public override MonthlyPeriod GetPreviousPeriod() => new MonthlyPeriod(StartDate.AddDays(-1));
```

This however has the obvious flaw that I specify the type of the method in the abstract class as being `Period`, not `MonthlyPeriod`.

Is there a straight forward way to define this type of relationship?

---

The best solution I've got so far is this:

1. Switch the abstract methods from `public` to `protected`.
2. Make the implemented abstract methods produce `Period`, as required.
3. In the abstract class define the following methods:

   ```
   public T GetPreviousPeriod<T>() where T : Period
   {
       T prevPeriod = GetPreviousPeriod() as T;
       if (prevPeriod == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException();
       }

       return prevPeriod;
   }

   public T GetNextPeriod<T>() where T : Period
   {
       T nextPeriod = GetNextPeriod() as T;
       if (nextPeriod == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException();
       }

       return nextPeriod;
   }
   ```

This works; however, it isn't necessarily a complete solution. In particular it's missing the compile time promise that the type is correct.

Comment: its in the nature of generics, you won't be able to get that compile time promise I'm afraid. Imagine Im using your assembly where `GetNextPeriod<T>`  is already compiled, and I supply my own class derived from Period..

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm trying to avoid :( I was thinking about marking Period as `internal`, but that's about as good as I think I could get, and then it kind of looses value as an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a solution that worked in context of my original question.

1. Change `Period` to `Period<T> where T : Period<T>`
2. Change `public abstract Period GetPreviousPeriod();` to `public abstract T GetPreviousPeriod();`
3. Repeat 2 for `GetNextPeriod()`.
4. Change `MonthlyPeriod : Period` to `MonthlyPeriod : Period<MonthlyPeriod>`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing that method on the base class, what if you create some extension methods, which create those new instances and returns them?

Also, it doesn't look right that a Period also works as a "PeriodFactory", as it violates the [S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

```
public static MonthlyPeriod GetNextPeriod(this MonthlyPeriod period)
{
    return new MonthlyPeriod(period.EndDate);
}
```

Comment: Looking at it again, you're right. An abstract factory pattern is the absolute correct way to deal with this. Extension methods still wouldn't get me there, since I wouldn't have the promise the future implementations made the correct extension method. For instance if FiscalYearPeriod "FY17" started Oct 1st, 2016 then I'd be in a world of hurt.

Comment: Sorry I unaccepted the answer here. It wasn't necessarily the "correct" answer to the question, and more diverting to a different approach to the problem. I was able to answer the specific question directly (see my answer).

Comment: That's okay, your answer is absolutely correct. You also should mark that as the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

You could define an interface like IPeriod and have that as the return type in the interface methods. Then your concrete implementations you can return MonthlyPeriod which would have implemented the interface IPeriod

Comment: What would be in the actual interface? I thought it was advised to not make marker interfaces like this. Edit: Not sure why you got down voted... it's a valid workaround.